# Is this the right way to do stable sorting in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm tring to do [this kattis problem (Sort of Sorting)](https://open.kattis.com/problems/sortofsorting), but my code only gets past the first trial. I've tried with my own sample cases and I don't see why it shouldn't work. Can someone check my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
while True:
    terms = eval(input())
    if terms == 0:
        break
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(terms):
        x.append(input())
    for i in range(terms):
        z = x[i][:2] + ' ' + str(i)
        y.append(z)
    y.sort()
    for i in range(terms):
        a,b = y[i].split()
        print(x[int(b)])
    print()
```

Comment: Ideally, provide an example of an input that it fails with, including both actual and expected results.

Comment: `'xx 2' > 'xx 11'`

Comment: `sort` is already stable. Read up on the `key` argument to [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).

Comment: You expect the input to be an integer, so use `int`, not `eval`. You'd rather get a `ValueError` than inadvertently execute a function call you didn't mean to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several issues. I'll add a comment for each one.

```
while True:
    terms = int(input())  # Technically, eval works here, but be careful!
    # Don't call eval with user input, that's a huge security issue.
    # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection
    if terms == 0:
        break
    names = []  # A more meaningful name
    for i in range(terms):
        names.append(input())
    # You don't need the other list, it only causes problems for you.
    # Including that it makes the sorting unstable (`2 < 11`, but `"2" > "11"`)
    # Instead, use the key argument to sort or sorted:
    names.sort(key=lambda name: name[:2])  # Python sort is stable
    for name in names:
        # Without the extra list, you can simply print the list
        # without trying to extract the original index
        print(name)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works.  Do you mind explaining why my code doesn’t work?

Comment: It's because you converted the indices to strings, and strings are sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), which is not the same as numeric ordering. Try `sorted([str(i) for i in range(100)])` to see how that looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` argument to `sort` (which is already stable) does what you are looking for.

```
x.sort(key=lambda x: x[:2])
```

No need to build a temporary list `y`.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why my solution doesn’t work?  It may not be efficient but I don’t see why it shouldn’t work.